# What is $R = 2\sin\theta \sin\phi$ (spherical coordinates) in cartesian coordinates?

Tags: calculus, education, spherical-coordinates

Hello I'm trying to figure out how to turn $R = 2\sin\theta \sin\phi$ (spherical coordinates) in cartesian coordinates.

**My attempt**
$$\begin{align}
&R = 2\sin\theta \sin\phi \\
&Rr = 2r\sin\theta \sin\phi \\
&Rr = 2y \\
&R \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 2y\\
&(x^2+y^2+z^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 2y
\end{align}$$
[image]

Can somebody tell me if I'm doing this right, because this looks wrong.
If you can help me, please do

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are $r$ and $R$?

Comment: I'm going to sent a picture

Comment: @rogerl I have added a picture

Comment: @rogerl I think $R$ is the distance from the origin to the point and $r$ is the length of the projection of that segment to the $xy$ plane.

Comment: You should have $y=R\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a mistake in your identity for $y$. In general spherical coordinates, we have the following identities
$$r=R\sin\phi$$
$$y=r\sin\theta=R\sin\phi\sin\theta$$
To apply these to the given equation, $R=2\sin\phi\sin\theta$, multiply both sides by $R$,
$$R^2=2R\sin\phi\sin\theta$$
$$R^2=2y$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2y$$
$$\boxed{x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1}$$

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much!